# How to fail a job if a condition is met?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have simplified my pipeline to these 2 steps:

```
  - task: LambdaInvokeFunction@1
    inputs:
      awsCredentials: $(AWS_CREDENTIALS)
      regionName: $(AWS_REGION)
      functionName: $(AWS_LAMBDA_NAME)
      payload: $(AWS_LAMBDA_PAYLOAD)
      outputVariable: "LambdaOutput"


  - script: |
      echo "I should run only if Lambda invokation had no error. In case of error, job must fail."
    condition: not(contains(variables['LambdaOutput'], 'error'))
```

I am using the *AWS toolkit for Azure Devops* and the task *LambdaInvokeFunction@1* doesn't fail itself when an error is returned upon invokation. So I'am using the output variable *LambdaOutput* to check for errors (I just look for the string 'error') during the next step.

Currently the second step will be skipped if there is an error, but I would like not only for the step to be skipped but the whole job to be in a **failed** state. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could negate the condition (so the script runs only when there's an error) and make the script fail the whole build:

```yaml
 - task: LambdaInvokeFunction@1
    inputs:
      awsCredentials: $(AWS_CREDENTIALS)
      regionName: $(AWS_REGION)
      functionName: $(AWS_LAMBDA_NAME)
      payload: $(AWS_LAMBDA_PAYLOAD)
      outputVariable: "LambdaOutput"


  - script: |
      echo "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Something went very wrong."
      exit 1
    condition: contains(variables['LambdaOutput'], 'error')
```

See [logging-commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#example-log-an-error) for more examples.